# Error: DATEPART does not exist, frp, SQL to select last months records

Tags: mysql, sql, function, datepart

I'm trying to get an SQL query to select all records from last month, I have this which from looking numerous places is exactly what I should need, and should work:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE DATEPART(yy,DateOrdered) = DATEPART(yy,DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE()))
AND DATEPART(m,DateOrdered) = DATEPART(m,DATEADD(m,-1,GETDATE()))
```

However I keep getting the error:

```
#1305 - FUNCTION retail.DATEPART does not exist
```

The query I'm using is word for word from other answers on here, yet I'm getting this error.

Thank you for any help -Tom

Answer (score 7, accepted):

DATEPART is a Transact-SQL function, usable with Microsoft SQL Server. From the question tags, I assume you are using MySQL as your Database Management System.

Take a look at [MySQL DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff)

Comment: ahhh, I'm still fairly new to all this, and keep slipping up on the different SQL. Thankyou.

Answer (score 3):

That would not work in mysql. 
To translate that to mysql you could do:

```
SELECT *
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(DateOrdered) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
AND MONTH(DateOrdered) = MONTH(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL -1 MONTH))
```

See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for the date functions available in mysql.

Answer (score 2):

It will also work.

```
SELECT * 
FROM orders 
WHERE  MONTH(DateOrdered) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH) 
AND YEAR(DateOrdered) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```